# SQL queries count

Tags: sql

Considérons une table commande avec 2 colonnes commande_id et valeur_total. On cherche à obtenir le nombre de commandes dont la valeur totale est entre 0 et 50 euros, entre 51 et 100 euros et enfin au dessus de 100 euros. Rédigez la requête SQL correspondante.

**English** version :

Consider a command table with 2 columns `command_id` and `value_total`. We seek to obtain the number of orders whose total value is between 0 and 50 euros, between 51 and 100 euros and finally over 100 euros. Write the corresponding SQL query.
Current code:

```
select count(*) from commande where Totale<=50 
Union 
select count(*)from commade where Totale>= 51 AND Totale <=100 
UNION 
select count(*) from commande where Totale>101
```

Comment: Please write a question in English language.

Comment: How far have you got with this homework?

Comment: just one condition the last one!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is okay. You should use `UNION ALL`, though, and add a column to say which count belongs to which range. E.g.:

```
select 'few'    as how_many, count(*) from commande where totale <= 50 
union all
select 'medium' as how_many, count(*) from commande where totale > 50 and totale <= 100 
union all
select 'many'   as how_many, count(*) from commande where totale > 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the 3 counters in 1 row like this:

```
select
  sum(case when value_total <= 50 then 1 else 0 end) counter1,
  sum(case when value_total > 50 and value_total <= 100 then 1 else 0 end) counter2,
  sum(case when value_total > 100 then 1 else 0 end) counter3
from commande
```

Another solution to get the counters in separate rows, 
provided that the column `value_total` is integer would be for **MySql**:

```
select 
  case (value_total - 1) div 50 
    when 0 then '(a) <=50'
    when 1 then '(b) >50 and <=100'
    else '(c) >100'
  end category, 
count(*) counter
from commande
group by category;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mE1wN9m6fYenL6uz9NeLUf/0)